# Python & OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pdf

Is there any Native Supports for Grabbing Images from PDFs or Create some sort of Object in Python that can contain the Images from a pdf that then can be access via OpenCV? I've looked at some scripts to dump the Images of a PDF into my directory but I'm aiming more at accessing the PDF and instead dumping the data from the PDF that is the image(s) into some sort of object I can access with OpenCV. My own exploration hasn't yielded any results so i figured I'd ask.

Added a Example of Using PyMuPDF based off example from @Ghilas BELHADJ

```
import fitz
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


class AccessPDF:

    def __init__(self):
        self.filepath = ""
        self.doc = None

    def openPDF(self):
        Tk().withdraw()
        self.filepath = askopenfilename()
        self.doc = fitz.open(self.filepath)

    def pixel2np(self,pix):
        im = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(pix.h, pix.w, pix.n)
        im = np.ascontiguousarray(im[..., [2, 1, 0]])  # rgb to bgr
        return im

    def displayKey(self):  
        pixobj = self.doc.getPagePixmap(0, alpha=False)
        im = self.pixel2np(pixobj)
        cv2.imwrite("testimg.png",im)
        cv2.imshow("Key" im)
```

Comment: Search `pdf2image`

Comment: I ran into that Module but I wasn't able to get it working and I chose not to pursue figuring out how to work it due to time constraints in my schedule. I'd reconsider if it would help me while using OpenCV and a PDF of Images. So I guess I should ask: Will it help me or do you recommend it over OpenCV

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to extract the images embedded in the PDF, rather than rendering the complete pages of the PDF as images? Do you have some sample PDF file?

Comment: Yes, I for have a pdf of scanned papers, I wanted to be able to be able to using tkinter to grab my file then display the first page which in itself is just a single image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Edit: I've made a modification in the code following the comment of @Dan Mašek*

You can achieve this (load the PDF **embedded images** into `OpenCV` without writing intermediate objects on disk) using [`PyMuPDF`](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [`Numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/).

In this example, I'm using [this pdf file](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/mediakit/assets/img/downloads/2018/NGM_2018_Media_Kit.pdf).

```py
import fitz
import cv2
import numpy as np


def pix2np(pix):
    im = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(pix.h, pix.w, pix.n)
    im = np.ascontiguousarray(im[..., [2, 1, 0]])  # rgb to bgr
    return im


doc = fitz.open('NGM_2018_Media_Kit.pdf')

# entire page
# pix = doc.getPagePixmap(0, alpha=False)

# first page , 5th image, xref element
pix = fitz.Pixmap(doc, doc.getPageImageList(0)[4][0])  
im = pix2np(pix)

cv2.putText(im, 'Azul fellawen', (100, 100),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.,
            (18, 156, 243), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imwrite('sample_0.png', im)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Thanks for pointing me to [Py]MuPDF, seems by far like the best lib for parsing and processing PDFs. (I've tried with PyPDF2 before you answered, but that needs a lot of code and grabbing the latest version apparently abandoned library from github :( -- yours is much more elegant :) )

Comment: Wow, This is a lot more helpful than what I originally had in mind. Now examing openCV i can just do cv2.imshow(im) right?

Comment: it's almost that  `cv2.imshow('some_title',im); cv2.waitKey(0)`

Comment: Alright, Thank you. Just to ask I'm not familiar with numpy what does the pix2np code do? I'm assuming to converts PyMuPDF's Pixmap object into something?

Comment: `pix2np` converts the `Pixmap` object into a [`numpy.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), which is the default format used by `cv2` to work with images.

Answer (score 2):

I've grabbed the images from an pdf containing images as well as text.

You can save the images using `pix.writePNG()` or just show it using `cv2.imshow()`, whichever suits you best.

```
import fitz    #pymupdf
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np

def pix2np(pix):
    im = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(pix.h, pix.w, pix.n)
    im = np.ascontiguousarray(im[..., [2, 1, 0]])  # rgb to bgr
    return im

def convertPdf(filename):  
    doc = fitz.open(filename)
    #count = 0
    for i in range(len(doc)):
        for img in doc.getPageImageList(i):
            xref = img[0]
            pix = fitz.Pixmap(doc, xref)

            #if pix.n < 5:       # this is GRAY or RGB
            # To save it to the disk
            #pix.writePNG(f"p{count}.png")

            im = pix2np(pix)
            cv2.imshow("image",im)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            #count += 1
            pix = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "sample.pdf"
    convertPdf(filename)
```