# Why the debug level is not working with this configuration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I noticed that nothig is written during logging with DEBUG level while launching my main script: python -m src.scripts, so i used the ipdb as follow:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join('logs','pdfparser.log'))
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

def pix2np(pix):
    """
    Convert pixmap to image
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059007/python-opencv
    """
    import numpy as np
    im = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(pix.h, pix.w, pix.n)
    try:
        im = np.ascontiguousarray(im[..., [2, 1, 0]])  # rgb to bgr
    except IndexError:
        #Trick to convert Gray rto BGR,
        logger.debug("Shape of image array is {}".format(im.shape)) 
        import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
        im = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
        im = np.ascontiguousarray(im[..., [2, 1, 0]])
    return im
```

And i entered manually the following commands

I just got the following result (in pdfparser.log):

```
ipdb> logger.info('test')
ipdb> logger.warning('test2')
ipdb> logger.debug('test2')
ipdb> logger.error('test2')
ipdb> logger.debug('test3')
ipdb> logger.error('test3')
ipdb> logger.exception('test3')
```

```
2020-10-22 11:13:51,498INFO:impocr.pdfparser:test
2020-10-22 11:14:10,004WARNING:impocr.pdfparser:test2
2020-10-22 11:14:49,745ERROR:impocr.pdfparser:test2
2020-10-22 11:15:13,497ERROR:impocr.pdfparser:test3
2020-10-22 11:16:35,722ERROR:impocr.pdfparser:test3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pincemaille\OneDrive - Groupe BPCE\Python\Impots\impocr\pdfparser.py", line 26, in pix2np
    im = np.ascontiguousarray(im[..., [2, 1, 0]])  # rgb to bgr
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\cmd.py", line 214, in onecmd
    func = getattr(self, 'do_' + cmd)
AttributeError: 'TerminalPdb' object has no attribute 'do_logger'
```

What is really strange is that logging.info works but not debug level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your logger level to `INFO`:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

That means anything you log at a level lower than `INFO` will be omitted. `DEBUG` is lower than `INFO`.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels

If you want debug messages included in your log, set the logger level to `logging.DEBUG` instead.

Comment: My bad i thought for any reason that info was lower than debug.Thanks