# Is it good practice to log an error which is different from the one raised?

Tags: python, logging

I am working with PyMuPDF which can return the pixmap associated with an image from the pdf filepath.

To work with numpy array I use the following function and understood that the "Index error" was raised quite often due to the shape of my image (which are gray and have a dimension (h,w,1) instead of BGR (h,w,3). So I log the error with my interpretation. Is it bad practice? If so what would you recommend?

```
def pix2np(pix):
        """
        Convert pixmap to image np.ndarray
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059007/python-opencv
        param pix: pixmap
        """
        import numpy as np
        #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236749/numpy-what-is-the-difference-between-frombuffer-and-fromstring
        im = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(pix.h, pix.w, pix.n)
        try:
            im = np.ascontiguousarray(im[..., [2, 1, 0]])  # rgb to bgr
        except IndexError:
            #Trick to convert Gray to BGR, (im.reshape)
            logger.warning("Convert Gray to BGR") 
            im = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
            im = np.ascontiguousarray(im[..., [2, 1, 0]])
        return im
```

Comment: I think in this case it would be better to simply check if the array has only one color channel and then convert it. There is no need to log such occurrences here as there is insufficient context to allow the reader of the log to change the situation.

Comment: Okay so just writing a condition instead of this try except block (i have been told that try except is preferred over if statement)